# Can't get correct output

Tags: c++, vector, hex

I have a project here I'm trying to solve

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:M_EjCxt7T34J:acm.uva.es/archive/nuevoportal/data/problem.php%3Fp%3D2286+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

And the problem I am having is the output keeps coming out to being slightly wrong instead of the last two being E1 it's E4 and in the middle of the zeros it's supposed to be 11F instead it's something like 12D or something this implies that it's doing mostly the right thing but I don't understand what is wrong. This is driving me nuts.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    //int count = 0;
    //GOOD
    int hexToInt(vector<char>& c);
    vector<char> intToHex(int n);
    int hexToInt(char c){
        if(c>='A')return c-'A'+10;
        else return c-'0';
    }
    void execute(vector<char>& memory){
      //  cout << "beb\n";

        char A = '0';
        char B = '0';
        if ((B>'9'&&B<'A')||(B<'0')||(B>'F')) cout << B << endl;
        for( size_t i = 0; i<memory.size();i++){
          //  cout << i << " "<< memory[i] <<endl;
           // if(count<100){
         //       cout << i << " " << memory[i]<<" "<< A << " "<< B <<endl;
             //   count++;
          //      cout << A << endl;
             //   cout << "I: "<< i<< " memory value: "<<memory[i]<<endl;
            //}
            vector<char> c;
            if(memory[i]-'0' == 0){
                c.push_back(memory[i+1]);
                c.push_back(memory[i+2]);
                A = memory[hexToInt(c)];
                i+=2;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 1){
                c.push_back(memory[i+1]);
                c.push_back(memory[i+2]);
                memory[hexToInt(c)] = A;
                i+=2;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 2){
                char temp = A;
                A = B;
                B = temp;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 3){
                int tempy = hexToInt(A)+hexToInt(B);
            //  if (count<100) cout << tempy<< "aaa"<<endl;
                c = intToHex(tempy);
            //  cout << "LOOK " <<tempy<< temp[0] << " "<<temp[1]<< " "<<A << " "<< B << endl;
                //Questionable****
                A = c[1];
                B = c[0];
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 4){
                if(A == 'F') A='0';
                else A +=1;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 5){
                if(A == '0') A='F';
                else A -=1;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 6){
                if(A=='0'){
                    c.push_back(memory[i+1]);
                    c.push_back(memory[i+2]);
                    if(hexToInt(c)>=240) i+=2;
                    else i = hexToInt(c)-1;
                }
                else i+=2;
            }
            else if(memory[i] -'0' == 7){
                c.push_back(memory[i+1]);
                c.push_back(memory[i+2]);
                if(hexToInt(c)>=240) i+=2;
                else i = hexToInt(c)-1;
            //  i+=2;
            }
            else /*if(memory[i] -'0' == 8)*/{
                if(i!=0) {
                for(size_t b = 0; b<memory.size();b++) cout << memory[b];
                }
                i = memory.size();
            //  cout <<"yayyyy";
            }
            if(memory[254]=='E'&& memory[64]=='1'&& memory[65]=='1'&& memory[66]=='F'&&memory[255]=='1')cout <<"fuuuu";
        //  cout << memory[255]<<endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int hexToInt(vector<char>& c){
        int ret = 0;
        int place = 1;
        for (int i = c.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(c[i]>='A') ret= ret+place*(c[i]-'A'+10);
            else ret= ret+place*(c[i]-'0');
            place*=16;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    //GOOD
    vector<char> intToHex(int n){
        vector<char> ret;
        int place = 16;
        while (!(place/16>n)){
            int curr = n%place/(place/16);
    //      if(count<100) cout<<n <<"bbb"<< curr << endl;
            if(curr<10) ret.push_back('0'+curr);
            else ret.push_back('A'+(curr-10));
            n-=curr;
            place*=16;
        }
        while(ret.size()<2) ret.push_back('0');
    //  if(count<100)cout << ret[0]<<ret[1]<<endl;
        int low = 0;
        int high = ret.size()-1;
        while(low<high){
            char temp = ret[low];
            ret[low]=ret[high];
            ret[high]=temp;
            high--;
            low++;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    int main () {
    //    int a = 7;
    //    vector<char> b = intToHex(a);
    //    for(int i = 0; i<b.size();i++){
    //        cout << b[i];
    //    }
    //    cout <<" " << hexToInt(b) << hexToInt('F')<< " "<< hexToInt('0') << endl;
        //GOOD
        ifstream ifs("test.txt");
        if(!ifs) cout << "wahh\n";
        vector<char> memory(256);
        while(ifs>>memory[0]){
           // cout << "weh\n";
            for (size_t i = 1; i<memory.size();i++){
                ifs>>memory[i];
                cout<<memory[i];
            //  cout << memory[i];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        //  cout << endl;
            execute(memory);
        }
    //  vector<int> wtf(256);
    //  for(int i = 0; i<wtf.size();i++){
    //      cout << i << " ";
    //        vector<char> temp = intToHex(i);
    //        for(int d = 0; d<temp.size(); d++){
    //            cout <<temp[d];
    //        }
    //        cout <<" "<< hexToInt(temp);
    //        if(i<16) cout<< " "<<hexToInt(intToHex(i)[1]);
    //        if(i!=hexToInt(intToHex(i)[1])) cout <<" HIOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO";
    //        cout << endl;
    //
    //  }
        char c = 'A'+1;
        cout << c;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

Comment: Could you try editing out all the debugging stuff, and explaining your algorithm? Have you considered doing a little refactoring?

Comment: What do you mean by refactoring?

Comment: It doesnt work. Do you mean make it neater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opcodes INC and DEC are wrong. If you look at the ASCII-Table you see that 'A' does not follow '9' so you have to "jump over" that gap.

The best way to do this is to just convert the hex-digits to an integer, increment/decrement the integer and convert it back. For example your DEC-opcode could look like that:

```
int temp = hexToInt(A);

if(temp == 0)
    temp = 0xf;
else
    temp -= 1;

vector<char> tempHex = intToHex(temp);
A = tempHex.back();
```

Comment: It would be nice if it were that way but no, after '9' follows ':' so `('9' + 1) == ':'` and `('A' - 1) == '@'`. There is a whole boatload of characters between them.

Comment: I dont see that error though perhaps we are loooking at something different? In hex A comes after 9